# Why does including a key in my XSL file produce a loading error?

Tags: xml, xslt

Whenever I include any mention of a key in my XSL file, Firefox produces the error:

```
Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.
```

Without including a key, the XSL loads as intended. Does this have something to do with the XSLT processor that I am using? Is Firefox the issue? How can I write my XSL file so that keys can be used?

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="b.xsl"?>
<root>
    <abc>
        <x>123</x>
    </abc>
    <abc>
        <x>456</x>
    </abc>
    <abc>
        <x>789</x>
    </abc>
</root>
```

And the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:value-of select="root/abc/x" />
            <xsl:key name="group-by-abc" match="abc" use="x" />
        </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:key...>` has to be always defined at the root level of the template (as child of `xsl:stylesheet`).

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#dt-top-level

Comment: It might be a good idea to develop and test your stylesheets in an environment other than the web browser, for example an XML IDE such as oXygen. You'll get much better diagnostics that way.